# Submit changes to database from DatGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a `DataGridView` on my form that I have associated with a data source using the designer. This allows me to customise the columns in the designer, which helps me a lot. My problem is that I now cannot work out how to submit changes made in the grid view to the database.

I have a `DataGridView` object, a `TableAdaptor` object and a `BindingSource` object - I cannot figure out which combination of calls to make to fluck all changes made in the grid to the database. Ideally, I would also be able to refresh the grids with the latest information from the database as well.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Oops - Straigth after posting I stumbled across the solution:

```
myTableAdaptor.update(MyDataSet);
```

For me, both the table adaptor and the data set had been auto-generated as class member variables.